# SX prop classes overridden by MUI theme

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to style a component using the *sx* MUI prop.

```
<Typography
        variant='h1'
        align='center'
        sx={{ fontSize: '24px', pb: '8px', fontWeight: '700' }}
    >
        Admin Panel
</Typography>
```

The problem is: classes from MUI theme have more CSS specificity and override those from *sx* prop.

Here is MUI theme setup for typography:

```
typography: {
        h1: {
            fontSize: '2rem',
            '@media screen and (min-width: 768px)': {
                fontSize: '3rem',
            },
            '@media screen and (min-width: 1024px)': {
                fontSize: '3.5rem',
            },
        },
    },
```

Here is also how it looks in dev tools:[image]

Is this expected behavior? Is there any way I can solve this?

Comment: I don't think that the theme rules always has greater specificity than sx. As you can see, the rule `fontSize: 2rem` hasn't taken over the sx rule. It is the media query that increases the specificity in your case. Consider adding the media query to your sx prop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is expected that styles from your theme have more specificity. the selector's weight of `@media screen and (min-width: 768px) .root'` is bigger than just of `.root`. Either add an `!important` to your `sx` prop (***what is not actually recommended***) or add the `@media sreen...` to your `sx` styles as well

Comment: Specifically, in v5 what worked for me was this syntax: `sx={{ fontSize: { xs: "24px" }, }} `, which sets the prop for the given breakpoint (here `xs`) and above, and overrides the ones set by the MUI theme. See MUI Docs: https://mui.com/system/getting-started/usage/#responsive-values

Comment: The {xs:"etc"} approach totally works! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Media queries do not increase specificity. It's the placement in the css file which will decide in this case.

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  body {
    background: salmon;
  }
}

body {
  background: beige;
}
```

will output a beige background on body, because it's defined after.

In OP's case, maybe MUI is putting media queries to the very end of the generated files, after all other sx?

(I'm posting an answer because I can't write code or paragraphs in comments… sorry for the social faux-pas)

And, I know it's very late and I hope OP has found a way, but I wanted to stress that **media queries do not increase specificity**.